# Magento Store - Cannot Edit Recently Viewed Block

Tags: magento

First post on StackExchange so I appreciate any help I can get.  I currently am reskinning/editing a Magento store for a client, but I can't seem to figure out how to edit or remove the "Recently Viewed" Tab on the left side.  You will see there are duplicates and I want to remove one of them.

Site:  http://dev.turboharp.com/online-store/what-s-new-1.html

I've looked throughout the static blocks and theme settings and can't find anything to edit this part of the theme.  Perhaps it is part of the template files?  If so I don't know where to look.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It's likely being added in the layout XML somewhere. This could either be in the xml files for the theme (like local.xml) or in layout updates configured somewhere in the back end. Do a search for "left.reports.product.viewed" in your theme xml files to see if you can find anything.

Comment: Turn on Template Path Hints and have a look.

Comment: There could also be a widget enabled for this in backend. Go to CMS-> Widgets and check if there is a widget instance created for displaying recently viewed products on left navigation.

Comment: @khartnett  Thank you!  This was the answer I needed.  I wasn't aware local.xml or catalog.xml were affecting the page layouts.  I guess this is where the Magento CMS can have a learning curve.  I was able to make additional edits via the local.xml page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in theme `local.xml` OR in `catalog.xml`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Basically you need to add the following code line

```
<remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
```

in left block reference.

Hope this help !!